# How to speed up this ElasticSearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build auto suggest based on the docs title. If the user types 'South', the auto suggest will suggest 'South Korea' for example. I used *shingle* filter to break the title to two words. Here my mapping :

```
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "suggestions_shingle":{
               "type":"shingle",
               "min_shingle_size":2,
               "max_shingle_size":2
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "suggestions":{
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[
                  "suggestions_shingle"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "docs":{
         "properties":{
            "docs_title":{
               "type":"multi_field",
               "fields":{
                  "docs_title":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "suggestions":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "analyzer":"suggestions",
                     "search_analyzer":"simple"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And Here is my query:

```
{
   explain:true,
   "aggs":{
      "description_suggestions":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"docs_title.suggestions",
            "size":10,
            "include":"South .*"
         }
      }
   },
   size:0
}
```

Here is the response from the query :

```
{
    "took": 2764,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 453526,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "description_suggestions": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 2363,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "South Korea",
                    "doc_count": 274
                },
                {
                    "key": "South India",
                    "doc_count": 179
                },
                {
                    "key": "South Carolina",
                    "doc_count": 179
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the query took 2764 to complete. How can I speed up this query?

I was thinking to run the aggregation query only on the last 2000 docs to speed it up by using filters. I noticed Elastic Search is ignoring the filter and it run the aggs on all docs. Here is query:

```
{
   explain:true,
   "aggs":{
      "recent_suggestions":{
         "filter":{
            "range":{
               "docs_date":{
                  "gte":1453886958
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "description_suggestions":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"docs_title.suggestions",
                  "size":10,
                  "include":"South .*"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   size:0
}
```

and here is the response:

```
{
    "took": 2216,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 453526,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "recent_suggestions": {
            "doc_count": 27240,
            "description_suggestions": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 173,
                "buckets": [
            {
                    "key": "South Korea",
                    "doc_count": 19
                },
                {
                    "key": "South India",
                    "doc_count": 17
                },
                {
                    "key": "South Carolina",
                    "doc_count": 17
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the total hits are the same.

How to make the two queries faster?

I'm using AWS ElasticSaerch v1.5.2 and Lucene v4.10.4 on a single instance.

Comment: Using include is taking down your performance. Check this link: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7526

Comment: I removed include but the performance still the same.

Comment: How many documents do you have? I've here index with 20 million documents with advanced aggregations, operation takes 22 milliseconds.

Comment: I have around 450k docs.

Comment: how does your doc_title look like? is it very big?

Comment: No, it has 5 words in average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that **ALL** documents are considered for aggregations which is very expensive and hence it takes so much time.

1) First query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "docs_title": "south"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "docs_title.suggestions",
        "size": 10,
        "include": "(?i)south .*",
        "execution_hint": "map"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

We only consider those documents that have `south` in them for aggregations. You did not specify any query and by default it was `match all` query. I have also added `(?i)` case insensitive flag in `include` so that it matches *south korea* and *South korea* both.

2) Second Query:

Again we need to narrow down the set of documents that satisfy our criteria for aggregation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "docs_title": "south"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "docs_date": {
            "gte": 1453886958
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "docs_title.suggestions",
        "size": 10,
        "include": "(?i)south .*",
        "execution_hint": "map"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Filtering by recent documents should be done inside query and not in aggregation in this case.

You should see considerable difference now. Previously aggregation was done on 450K docs and now it should be much smaller.

**EDIT1** : [This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7526) provides more details on why `include/exclude` is costly on **high cardinality** fields which `doc_title.suggestions` is(shingles increases this much more). @markharwood commented on that issue

> The root cause is that the IncludeExclude.acceptedGlobalOrdinals()
>   method enumerates terms eagerly for all terms in the index rather than
>   lazily for those in the result set. For a high cardinality field this
>   can take a very long time

so basically, aggs is going through all the terms in the index. The solution is to use `"execution_hint": "map"` in aggregation which will avoid loading global ordinals. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint) on that. Also there is not 100% assurance. From the docs

> Please note that Elasticsearch will ignore this execution hint if it
>   is not applicable and that there is no backward compatibility
>   guarantee on these hints.

It will be considered when few documents match query which is the case here.

**Note** : This might be completely unrelated but you might want to look into [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html), although it only works when string begins with specific letters.

Comment: I tried the second query. the total hits are around 100 but the query time still 2000ms. {
    "took": 2380,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 59,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {..} }}

Comment: ok, could you try without aggregation and let us know how much time it took? also how long is you title field?

Comment: In average, the title have 5 words. here is the result after i removed the aggs {
    "took": 14,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 35,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    }
}

Comment: I see, I am not sure why aggs on 200 docs taking so long, could you remove `include` and let me know the time(my suspicion is regex)? and what about the first query? any improvements?

Comment: The first query is slow too. I noticed When the query have include, the  query takes around 2000ms and if I run it again it takes around 1000ms and if I run it after 3-5 seconds it takes around 2000ms.
When I remove include, the  query takes around 1500 ms to complete and if I run it again, it takes only 50ms, after 3 seconds, it goes to 1500 ms.

Comment: I think, ES is considering lot of values for aggregations. [This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7526) will shed more light on this. Try adding `"execution_hint": "map"` in aggregation and update us with results. Also what is the configuration of your single instance? how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now it take only 60ms without the filter. please update your answer to include the hint. Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help, I also learned some new stuff :)  I have updated my answer.